# Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the flickr api to get pull and display some photos. This is the code I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON(" https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=4323f337ae15b2555681e8c9c5b111e1e&lon=-87.6321&per_page=3&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", displayImages);
    function displayImages(data) {  
        $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
            var photoID = item.id;
            $('#photos').append(photoID); 
            var htmlString = '<img src="' + photoURL + '">';            
            $('#photos').append(htmlString); 
            $('#photos').append("<br/><hr/><br/>");
        }); 
    }
});
```

can someone please tell me the fix for this, and where I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CORS with `jsonp` instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=4323f337ae15b2555681e8c9c5b111e1e&lon=-87.6321&per_page=3&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.photos.photo, function (i, item) {
            var photoID = item.id;
            $('#photos').append(photoID);
            var htmlString = '<img src="' + photoURL + '">';
            $('#photos').append(htmlString);
            $('#photos').append("<br/><hr/><br/>");
        });
    }
});
```